# apex checkmarx tampering issue

Tags: apex, checkmarx

how to solve the error in checkmarx?

Id clientId = (id)inputMap.get('ClientId')

Account a= [Select Id, Client__c, ParentId, Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName,CI_ClientID__c
from Account where Id = :clientId limit 1000]
but its not working.

error is : Method invokeMethod gets user input from element inputmap. This input is later concatenated by the application directly into a string variable containing SQL commands, without being validated. This string is then used in method to query the database select, at line 55 without any additional filtering by the database. This could allow the user to tamper with the filter parameter.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this code will help you because this error is related to the use of input data from the user without validation. Checkmarx warns that code may be vulnerable to attacks.

```
Id clientId = (Id)inputMap.get('ClientId');

if (clientId != null) {
    // Escaping user input before using it in a query
    String escapedClientId = String.escapeSingleQuotes(clientId);
    
    Account a = [
       SELECT Id, Client__c, ParentId, Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName, CI_ClientID__c 
       FROM Account 
       WHERE Id = :escapedClientId 
       LIMIT 1000
    ];

} else {
    // Error or action to take if the value is missing clientId
}
```